# Failed to run android sdk manager in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sdk

I'm trying to code an app for android and I ran into a problem with the sdk manager.  When I try to run it in eclipse, it says *"Failed to run android sdk manager. Check the Android Console View for Details."* Then in the console it says:

> [2013-01-30 21:27:45 - SDK Manager] Missing %s file in Android SDK.
>
> [2013-01-30 21:27:45 - SDK Manager] android.bat

I reinstalled eclipse, the sdk and tried everything any other posts about the same problem but nothing works.

Comment: Did you configure the path for your SDK Manager? Is the .bat file inside the folder? You can google to download the android.bat file and placed it in if needed

Answer (score 2):

I was able to restore the missing items in File | New... quite easily by performing the following steps:

- Switch to the Java perspective, either via the perspective switcher
  toolbar at the top right of the main Eclipse window, or via the
  Window | Open Perspective menu item.
- Reset the perspective by either right-clicking on the Java
  perspective icon in the perspective switcher toolbar, or by clicking 
  Window | Reset Perspective...

As to why they weren't there in the first place, the most likely cause would be that the ADT contributes various things to the Java perspective, and these changes don't take effect until the perspective is reset after installing the ADT. As an Eclipse plug-in developer I learned it the hard way, that changes to perspectives don't get picked up unless you explicitly reset them.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that your SDK has the android.bat file. By looking in the directory the SDK is in.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try: `chmod +x <ADTFolder>/sdk/tools/android`

Answer (score 0):

Unzip your sdk zip somewhere, copy entire contents of tools directory, replace it with your actual sdk tools folder contents.

Restart eclipse if needed.